# Displayin the date of creation in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I previously asked a similar question, but still didn't get a working answer.
So I have in my database a table wich contains informations about users(first_name,email...) and 2 fields containing the date of creation("created") and the date of update("updated").
the "updated" field has the type TIMESTAMP ,default ="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", attributs ="on Current_timestamp" . And the "created" field has type="datetime" and not null default="none".
The problem is when displaying the date of creation, I got next to each user "0000-00-00 00:00:00".
Here is the code that adds a user to the database:

```
$first_name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
$username = trim($_REQUEST['username']);
$password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$created = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password, email, created)" .
"VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($last_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($username),
mysql_real_escape_string(crypt($password, $username)),
mysql_real_escape_string($email),
mysql_real_escape_string($created));
mysql_query($insert_sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Please help, I tried various functions like date(), now() but still doesn't work.

EDIT: that what my table shows:

```
mysql> SELECT updated, created from users;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| updated             | created             |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-09-21 09:09:49 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 2012-09-21 09:27:27 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 2012-09-22 11:36:19 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 2012-09-22 11:43:35 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entering a string in a timestamp field; instead use the [*mysql function* `NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).  Your query should be:

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (
     `first_name`,
     `last_name`,
     `username`,
     `password`,
     `email`,
     `created`) VALUES (
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            NOW())"
```

Also, consider migrating to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to take advantage of prepared statements.

To clarify the comments; it won't matter what type the field is, as MySQL will know how to deal with it if you give it `NOW()`:

```
mysql> create table temp (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ts TIMESTAMP, dt DATETIME);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into temp values ('',NOW(),NOW()),('',NOW(),NOW());
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.08 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from temp;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | ts                  | dt                  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2012-09-22 13:38:50 | 2012-09-22 13:38:50 |
|  2 | 2012-09-22 13:38:50 | 2012-09-22 13:38:50 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It won't work, if you try to insert `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
mysql> insert into temp values ('',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from temp order by id desc limit 1;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | ts                  | dt                  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  7 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The OP says explicitly it's a DATETIME field -> 'And the "created" field has type="datetime" ' so you are guessing it's TIMESTAMP, right?

Comment: It won't matter what type it is; MySQL knows what to do with `NOW()`.

Comment: this is what is strange, NOW() normally should work but it's the case. howerver, when I enter to phpmyadmin, the "updated" field stores the exact time while "created" stores zeros.

Comment: Update the question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for your table.

Comment: Type `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` then paste the output. The zeros tell me that you are inserting the literal timestamp and not a proper type that MySQL can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the records have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as their timestamp values. 
This is a normal issue if you alter a table, `create column timestamp (not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) in MYSQL`, it updates the previous records with timestamp `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

The solution is to update the database records to have values other than `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Hope that helps !

Comment: Yes the records show 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the created field but the exact time in the updated field.

Comment: So you are good? You can always select some other value when created field is 0000-00-00? Something like SELECT IF(created = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', created) AS created

Comment: Check this SQL - _select test.price, test.brid, (select if(test.timestamp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', NOW(), test.timestamp)) as time from test ;_ And my table is _CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)_. Hope that helps !

Comment: I was working on a copy of the file that creates users -_- !now() works fine .thanks for the help anyway.Lol I don't believe myself.

Answer (score 0):

As your field is a timestamp, you need to enter in a [timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
INSERT INTO users 
    (first_name, last_name, username, password, email, created)
    VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: My "created" field is a datetime .

Comment: Sorry, misread it, if that is the case, the answer that @BurhanKhalid gave, should work?